# Page transitions, depending on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This code fades each page out, before going to the URL's destination. However, there are some instances where the user doesn't go to a new page, but goes to a PDF in the browser, or it opens the default mail application. On Safari it seems, if you go to an external site (www.twitter.com) and press the back button, the `.wrapper` is still faded out. (Perhaps a cache thing?)

```
function fadeAndGo(x) {

        $(x).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href;
        $('.wrapper').fadeOut(function(){
            window.location = href;

        });
        // $('.wrapper').delay()fadeIn();
    });
}

fadeAndGo('a');
```

Is it possible to either:

- Fade out, only if the URL does not contain 'PDF, mailto', or is an external link?
- Fade in after a certain amount of time (it faded out, but faded back in after a couple of seconds, in case it was a PDF/mailto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function fadeAndGo(x) {
    $(x).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        if (!/PDF|mailto/gi.test(href)) {
            $('.wrapper').fadeOut(function () {
                window.location = href;
            }).delay(2000).fadeIn();
        } else {
             window.location = href;
        }
    });
}

fadeAndGo('a');
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a logical way for it to fade back in after 2 seconds? When I try putting .delay(2000) on, it ceases to leave at all.